# Jetty connector and handlers

Tags: java, jetty

Currently I am creating a embedded server like this:

```
Server server = new Server(8080);

ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler();
handler.setContextPath("/abc");

handler.addServlet( ...);
handler.addServlet(....);
handler.addServlet(....);

server.SetHanlder(handler);

server.start();
server.join();
```

So I am not explicitly creating a connector in the above.
If I want to create a connector, how does that effect things?

Can a server have more then one connectors?  Is there a default connector created, and if I create one explicitly, it will use that?

The reason I think I need a connector is that I want to explicitly set some properties that the actual server instance doesn't have.

I'm a bit confused as to what a connector is for.

Answer (score 2):

The connector is for accepting and handling the initial incoming connections.

By default the basic HTTP (non-SSL) connector is setup based on the port you provided on the `new Server(8080);` line.  It should be listening on port 8080 on all network interfaces for your machine.

If you want to serve SSL or SPDY you'll need the appropriate SSL connector based on your version of Jetty (javadoc: [Jetty 6](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6/apidocs/org/mortbay/jetty/Connector.html), [Jetty 7/8](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Connector.html), [Jetty 9](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ServerConnector.html)).

Or if you want to only listen on specific network interfaces, you'll want to configure your connector appropriately.

Comment: If I want to set the port, reuseaddress, maxidletime, etc., I have to add a connector to my server right?  I don't see these properties on the server instance itself.

Comment: the Server.setConnectors() is what you want. See the embedded examples: http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/example-jetty-embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/ManyConnectors.java?h=jetty-8